# Add array to Collection in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, collections

So I basically have a list of rows in excel containing data from a calendar, all with each user who created them.  I am making a collection of objects with each users.  After adding the individual to the 1st collection I then have another collection called "Events" inside the user object.  This is where the event type and dates are stored.  I have having trouble adding an array to the Collection "Events".

The "user" object looks like this:

> **User**
>
> -Name
>
> -Events [event1, event2, event3, ..., etc]

I'm getting the error of "**Object variable or With variable not set**"  Here are the lines taken from the code below at the end of the neested if and else if statements that give this error:

> temp.Events.Add arr1
>
> emp2.Events.Add arr2

**Code:**

```
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 5))
Dim name As String
'grab name in cell
name = Cells(i, 5)
'if first list item, add new user
If list.Count = 0 Then
    Dim emp1 As New User
    emp1.name = name
    list.Add emp1
Else
    'traverse through list and search for same name
    For j = 1 To list.Count
        'if name is present, add event data to user object
        If list.Item(j).name = name Then
            Dim temp As New User
            Set temp = list.Item(j)
            Dim arr1(2) As String
            arr1(1) = Cells(i, 3)
            arr1(2) = Cells(i, 1)
            temp.Events.Add arr1
        'if name is not present, add new user and event data to new user object
        ElseIf j = list.Count Then
            Dim emp2 As New User
            emp2.name = name
            Dim arr2(2) As String
            arr2(1) = Cells(i, 3)
            arr2(2) = Cells(i, 1)
            emp2.Events.Add arr2
            list.Add emp2
        End If
    Next
End If

    i = i + 1
Loop
```

If there is any easier way of doing this or if this isn't possible please point me in the right direction.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In the constructor for your `User` object, do you initialize `Events`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your User class add the method Class_Initialize and initialize your variables.  Now this only gets called on the first method used so when you use

```
Dim temp As New User
```

it is still not initialized until you call a method of the object.

You will want to use the below way to initialize it before use

```
Dim temp As User
set temp = New User 'now it is initialized
```

In your User Class

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
'code here 
End Sub
```

Comment: That is not correct.  Objects can be initialized with a `Dim` statement; as an example, try creating a new FileSystemObject with `Dim FSO as New FileSystemObject`.  It is immediately usable without a `Set` statement.

Comment: Initialization was the problem. Sorry, first time using VBA, all of the class creating tutorials I could find were awful.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Sorceri, you're right that `class_initialize()` doesn't get called until the first method call--which I didn't know.  But it also gets called before the first property call.  The example you gave at MS Support refers to trying to access a global property before its value gets set during `class_initialize()`, which is indeed an unexpected problem.  But in this case the issue is with a `User` class property, so the constructor gets called before the property is invoked.